# Replanting daffodil - couldn't find bulb

Tags: bulbs, daffodils, replant

This morning I replanted a stray daffodil (hasn't bloomed yet) that had grown just outside of our garden bed in our lawn.

I noticed after digging a deep hole and lifting out the daffodil that there was no bulb, only the green stalks.

Is this unusual? Was this a shoot that had grown from a nearby plant into the lawn?

Comment: How deep is "deep" ? I seen feral daffodils below 8 in.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Oh about 5 inches - yea I may have clipped off the stalks from the bulb.